# Do I need to file an amended US tax return for a missing 1098?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, amended-tax-return, form-1040x

I just filed my 2021 US form 1040 tax return yesterday. Earlier today, I discovered that I'd missed entering a form 1098.

I used TurboTax to do the filing, so I opened it up and clicked the "file amended return" button and entered the 1098 information. TurboTax is reporting that there is no difference between this 1040-X and my original 1040 and says that I don't need to file an amended return.

Is there likely to be any issue with getting flagged by the IRS because they already have the 1098 from the mortgage lender but I don't have it reported in what I filed in my 1040?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that this isn't a rental property.

> Is there likely to be any issue with getting flagged by the IRS
> because they already have the 1098 from the mortgage lender but I
> don't have it reported in what I filed in my 1040?

If you took the standard deduction, then the mortgage interest doesn't impact you federal taxes. The IRS won't be looking for it because you didn't need it.

Of course if adding in the numbers for your mortgage interest would put you over the standard deduction then you also want to change via the 1040x from the standard deduction to itemizing.

if you were already itemizing then the mortgage interest numbers would be very important to be able to claim all your deductions., and I would have expected to see your taxes change.

It is also possible that if you bought this house late in the year that the amount of interest wasn't enough to take you above the standard deduction. But next year you will have 12 months of interest so you need to make sure you include the 2022 1098 in your taxes.

If this is a rental property, then you will want to include the 1098, because  you always want to include that cost in your tax calculation

Note: the IRS will never require you to include your mortgage interest 1098 for your personal residence  if you don't want to itemize. That is always up to you.

Comment: Thank you. This makes it very clear _why_ I don't have to file an amendment and that is very useful and probably what I should have asked in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no difference then there's nothing to amend. You're not reporting the 1098 to the IRS, your bank does. You are reporting your tax liability to the IRS. If that doesn't change then you don't need to change your report.